how to display count value at above every bar chart in ireport jasper
i have make new bar chart. but i want to display the number of count at above every bar. How to do that?
This is bar chart without count at above
i want like this:
The every bar have own count based on data.
This is bar chart with count at above
Any idea how to solve that?

i got answer:
[Chart plot-> show label =TRUE] : https://i.sstatic.net/o3w7BhA4.jpg
[Chart Wizard -> put $F{QTY}.toString()]
: https://i.sstatic.net/AJq010C8.jpg
